# What are the some banks for businesses looking to handle *everything* online?

Tags: united-states, small-business, online-banking

My business works with contractors and customers around the world and I have plans for long-term travel for myself. The small local bank I'm currently with doesn't seem like a good fit for my company. I'm looking for a bank that can handle all of my transactions online. My highest priorities are:

1. Low/no fees
2. Ability to send international ACH and wires online
3. Bill pay
4. Remote deposit with no additional hardware (Scan paper checks for deposit)
5. A web interface that doesn't suck

Comment: Is "mail this check in for deposit" an acceptable alternative for #4?

Comment: Don't rule out local banks. You might ask around at other locals. With the exception of #4 a small local bank near me has everything you're looking for.

Comment: @fennec @Vitalik Ideally it'd be the ability to send a digital image I create via a scanner or my webcam. I'd settle for iPhone or mail-in if it came to it though.

Comment: @bstpierre My local bank falls on its face when it comes to numbers 4 and 5.

Comment: All I meant was that there may be others locally that can do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Chase allows you to take a picture of checks and deposit into your accounts (free for personal checking customers) works on iPhone + android

Obviously, they have bill payment.

You can ACH money to/from YOUR accounts at other banks.

You get the benefit of finding a branch in many cities around the world.

As for "web interface that doesn't suck", well... that's kinda personal. I think  it's not too bad.